# Is there a way to list the kernel threads that are created by the kernel only?

Tags: linux

The command `ps aux | grep ]` will list all the running kernel threads (the kernel threads that are crated by the kernel, and the kernel threads that are crated by someone else).

Is there a way to list the kernel threads that are created by the kernel only?

Answer (score 2):

Kernel threads are always created by the kernel, and they’re always in process group 0, so you can filter on that:

```
ps -e -o pid,ppid,pgid,args | awk '$3 == 0'
```

(There doesn’t seem to be a way of filtering on process group id in `ps`; in theory one could filter on session 0 but `ps` doesn’t like that.)

You can also look for processes whose parent is `kthreadd`, the kernel thread dæmon:

```
ps --pid 2 --ppid 2 -o pid,ppid,pgid,args
```

(including pid 2 and its children).

Comment: *"Kernel threads are always created by the kernel"* By "Kernel" do you mean the kernel and the kernel modules or just the kernel by itself (because I think `kthread_create()` is used by kernel modules to create kernel threads)?

Comment: Yes, both the kernel and kernel modules; I tend not to distinguish them since most modules can be built in, and once loaded, modules are effectively part of the kernel.

Comment: You could perhaps distinguish between threads started by the “core” kernel from those started by modules by looking at `etimes` in `ps`.