# Where is the process scheduler running? Can I track it?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, scheduling

Is the process scheduler "visible" at user space? Can I see it with ps? Maybe is it one of the kernel threads? If yes, how is it called? How can I "see" it?

> It doesn’t exist as a separate thread, or module, it’s implemented as
> a function

Ok, but how and where and in which way is this function run? Is there a way to track it and see it?

Comment: A common metaphor is to think of the system as a plate of spaghetti. The threads are, naturally, the strands of spaghetti; the scheduler is the sauce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [What's the process scheduler in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/486182/86440) the scheduler is a kernel function, [`__schedule`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.3/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L6151); it doesn’t appear as a separate thread or process.

The function comment explains how it is run:

```
 * The main means of driving the scheduler and thus entering this function are:
 *
 *   1. Explicit blocking: mutex, semaphore, waitqueue, etc.
 *
 *   2. TIF_NEED_RESCHED flag is checked on interrupt and userspace return
 *      paths. For example, see arch/x86/entry_64.S.
 *
 *      To drive preemption between tasks, the scheduler sets the flag in timer
 *      interrupt handler scheduler_tick().
 *
 *   3. Wakeups don't really cause entry into schedule(). They add a
 *      task to the run-queue and that's it.
 *
 *      Now, if the new task added to the run-queue preempts the current
 *      task, then the wakeup sets TIF_NEED_RESCHED and schedule() gets
 *      called on the nearest possible occasion:
 *
 *       - If the kernel is preemptible (CONFIG_PREEMPTION=y):
 *
 *         - in syscall or exception context, at the next outmost
 *           preempt_enable(). (this might be as soon as the wake_up()'s
 *           spin_unlock()!)
 *
 *         - in IRQ context, return from interrupt-handler to
 *           preemptible context
 *
 *       - If the kernel is not preemptible (CONFIG_PREEMPTION is not set)
 *         then at the next:
 *
 *          - cond_resched() call
 *          - explicit schedule() call
 *          - return from syscall or exception to user-space
 *          - return from interrupt-handler to user-space
```

The function can’t be traced; [its instrumentation is disabled](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=499d795) (see the `notrace` entry in its declaration).

Comment: if it is a kernel function, the kernel is "invisible"...? Does it fight against other processes/threads for cpu time?  How is being executed?

Comment: The kernel isn’t invisible, it’s the “system” part of CPU time (*e.g.* in `top`). Kernel code is executed whenever a process calls it (through a system call) or whenever an interrupt occurs. It doesn’t fight with processes for CPU time, it enables processes to do their work.

Comment: thanks for answer. `it’s the “system” part of CPU time (e.g. in top).` what do you mean?

Comment: Run `top`, and look at the “sy” value in the “%Cpu(s)” line — that’s the system time, “sy, system: time running kernel processes” (in the `top` man page). You’d also need to add “hi” and “si”, the time spent servicing interrupts. IIRC this doesn’t count the time spent handling system calls; that’s done in service of the calling process and counted against that process. You can see the time spent in system calls by running `time`.

Comment: thanks a lot!! time always show me 0 though... anyway, one question: why do you say that kernel doesn't fight with processes for CPU time? this `sy` value actually shows that this is time that processor execute the kernel code, not user program code... so in some way kernel also fights for cpu time... another question: are these `sy` things invisible at user space? they are not threads/processes so they are not "visible" for the user, right?

Comment: OK, so yes, the time spent running the kernel is time not available to run user processes, but it’s handling essential work so I don’t really see it as a fight; in other words, the system can’t choose not to run the kernel when it needs to, otherwise nothing else happens. `sy` covers time spent in kernel threads, which are visible as processes; they are all [children of the `kthreadd` process (pid 2)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508538/86440).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help... but you said that process scheduler is not a thread... and then you said that kernel can be seen in `sy` section with top... but now you say that `sy` shows kernel threads...... so I am confused...

Comment: The scheduler is a small part of the kernel. It doesn’t show up as a kernel thread, but other tasks in the kernel are handled as threads. My comment about the kernel not being invisible was about the kernel as a whole.

Comment: Thanks again. So `sy` does not cover all kernel actions (for example, not the scheduler), am I wrong?